# Security restrictions when calling Javascript within a iOS UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, security, uiwebview, webview

I'm researching the viability of an iOS app that will open up multiple UIWebViews in the background and log into multiple websites based on userdata data entered into the original app.
The main app will be driving the hidden webviews by executing Javascript to obtain(scrape) data from the pages for cost comparison and then executing actions if desired.
The website are using https.

Are there any security restrictions or other problems related to this I need to be aware of?

Thanks

J